# ImportError: cannot import name 'Bot' from 'telegram' (unknown location)

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I started programming a telegram bot with python right know and stocked at the first code :

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler

updater = Updater('1670111367:AAHEzzfNQUeWL9ylptnDyQPZjarACLNUcGc')


def start(bot,update):
    chat_id=update.message.chat_id
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id,"hello")

start_command=CommandHandler('start',start)

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_command)


updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

but I get this Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smjt2000/Programming/Projects/Telegram_Bot/1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
  File "/home/smjt2000/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .basepersistence import BasePersistence
  File "/home/smjt2000/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/basepersistence.py", line 25, in <module>
    from telegram import Bot
ImportError: cannot import name 'Bot' from 'telegram' (unknown location)
```

I read the documents but I can't fix it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not post your token key here.
And I think the error is on the function declaration. You should also import "CallbackContext" and use "update.message.reply_text" (instead of bot.sendMessage). Take a look at this "[Hello World bot](https://python-telegram-bot.org/)" in the main page of the project.